# Why is the Hessian in the Laplace approximation negative

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, derivative, hessian, laplace-approximation

The Laplace approximation builds from the Taylor expansion of the MAP estimate, where the first derivative is 0. The second order Taylor series goes...

$$
f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x - a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x - a)^2
$$

and so therefore, the Laplace approximation would omit the second order term, leaving...

$$
f(a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x - a)^2
$$

But every piece of material I see refers to the second derivative as negative. For example, slide 6 of this presentation [https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~jurcicek/NPFL108-BI-2014LS/04-approximate-inference-laplace-approximation.pdf](https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ejurcicek/NPFL108-BI-2014LS/04-approximate-inference-laplace-approximation.pdf) says

$$
\log f(w) \approx log f(w) + \frac{1}{2}A(w - w_0)^2
$$

where $A = -\frac{d^2 \log f(w)}{dw^2}$ but why is the sign negative on $A$?

### EDIT: Another example:

Page 41 of this text http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW3.pdf

$$
q(\mathbf{f}| X, y) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}, \hat{\mathbf{f}}, A^{-1}) \propto \exp{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{f} - \hat{\mathbf{f}})A(\mathbf{f} - \hat{\mathbf{f}})}
$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{f}} = \arg\max_{\mathbf{f}} p(\mathbf{f}|X, y)$ and $A = -\nabla\nabla\log p(\mathbf{f}|X, y)$ is the Hessian of the negative log posterior at that point.

In this case, does the negative log posterior just distribute into the Taylor series like so...

$$
-\Big(f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x - a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x - a)^2\Big)
$$

Comment: Doesn't the M in "MAP" refer to *maximum?*  What is the sign of the second derivative at a local maximum?

Comment: It should be negative, but that is part of the derivative itself, not an added negative sign. If the derivative is negative and I am supposed to take the negative of that, then it should be positive. Either way, it seems to me there is an addition of a random negative sign which shouldn't be there. What am I not seeing?

Comment: The added negative sign could either be from defining $\log f$ as the negative log likelihood or it could be a typo.  An examination of the context shows it's a typo.

Comment: I added another example, can you check that my understanding is correct? Thanks for the help

Comment: Since its likely the approximation is from a point of maximum, the second derivative is negative. However, in most cases these must be solved numerically and having the Hessian to be positive definite is likely to have smoother solutions while using gradient based approaches. So the negative is brought outside likely to make the second derivative positive definite and the numerical solution to be smoother.

Comment: ok, but then how do you rectify the fact that you just added a negative into an equation which shouldn't have it?

Comment: Everything in the edit looks fine: the negative log density will be *minimized,* making $A$ positive-semidefinite at any such local minimum, which is required for $A^{-1}$ to be the covariance matrix of a multivariate Normal distribution.